# Udemy Complete Python Bootcamp by Pieren Data Function exercise

Tags: python-3.x, function

The question was to define a function that takes in a string and returns matching string where every even letter is uppercase and every odd letter is lowercase. The function considers that string only contains letters. 
 The answer for it was:

```
 def myfunc(x):
    string = []
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if i % 2==0:
            string.append(x[i].lower())
        else:
            string.append(x[i].upper())
    return ''.join(string)
```

Is there different ways to solve without using .join()?

Comment: @Kim If you're a posting a question here, make sure that the title explains your problem (in a concise manner), and not simply the source from where you got an Exercise question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
def myfunc(x):
    newString=""
    for i in range (len(x)):
        if(i%2==0):
            newString+=x[i].upper()
        else:
            newString+=x[i].lower()       
    return newString
```